# NumPy: How to check if a tuple is in a 1D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples, python-imaging-library

I'm having some trouble trying to check if a python tuple is in a one dimensional numpy array. I'm working on a loop that will record all the colors present in an image and store them into an array. It worked well using normal lists, but the image is very large and I think NumPy Arrays will speed up the loop as it took several minutes to complete the loop.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open("bg.jpg").convert("RGB")
pixels = img.load()

colors = np.array([])

for h in range(img.size[1]):
    for w in range(img.size[0]):
        if pixels[w,h] not in colors:
            colors = np.append(colors, pixels[w,h])
        else:
            continue
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  if pixels[w,h] in colors:
```

Thanks in advance, and if you know a faster way to do this please let me know.

Comment: Using numpy arrays will generally not speed up a loop. The advantage of numpy is in vectorization. What is the shape of `pixels`? Is it 3D? Height and width and three color channels? What do you want? A list of unique colors in the image? *How* unique? Do you want to consider `(255, 255, 255)` different than `(255, 255, 253)`? How do you want to store your colors? As tuples? Or as a 3D array?

Comment: @ddejhon Each color stored will be unique, so yes, (255, 255, 255) will be different from (255, 255, 253). The color mode is `RGB` and the colors will be stored as tuples but in an array/list. The array would obviously be 2 dimensional, with each dimension having 4 elements.

Comment: Wait, you want a 2D array of the colors at each pixel? You want not only the unique colors in the image, but their locations? What are the 4 elements? R, G, B, and...?

Comment: Can you please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @ddejhon sorry, I meant 3 elements. Yes, a 2d array with 3 elements containing the RGB values. The problem I'm having is checking if the pixel color (the tuple) is in the array, but if I do it the way shown above, I get an error. So my question once again is, how can I check if a tuple is in a NumPy array that is 1 dimensional?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `pixels` is of shape `(3, w, h)` or `(3, h, w)` (i.e., the color channels are along the first axis), and assuming all you're after are the unique colors in the image:

```py
channels = (channel.flatten() for channel in pixels)
colors = set(zip(*channels))
```

If you want a `list` instead of a set, `colors = list(set(zip(*channels)))`.

You seem to be misunderstanding where numpy comes in handy. A numpy array of tuples is not going to be any faster than a a Python list of tuples. The speed of numpy comes into play in numerical computation on matrices and vectors. A numpy array of tuples cannot take advantage of any of the things that make numpy so fast.

What you're trying to do is simply *not appropriate* for numpy, and won't help speed up your code at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need exactly. But i hope the next piece of code will help you.

```
import numpy as np

image = np.arange(75).reshape(5, 5, 3) % 8

# Get the set of unique pixles
pixel_list = image.reshape(-1, 3)
unique_pixels = np.unique(pixel_list, axis = 0)

# Test whether a pixel is in the list of pixels:
i = 0
pixel_in_list = (unique_pixels[i] == pixel_list).all(1).any(0)
# all(1) - all the dimensions (rgb) of the pixels need to match
# any(0) - test if any of the pixels match

# Test whether any of the pixels in the set is in the list of pixels:
compare_all = unique_pixels.reshape(-1, 1, 3) == pixel_list.reshape(1, -1, 3)
pixels_in_list = compare_all.all(2).any()
# all(2) - all the dimensions (rgb) of the pixels need to match
# any()  - test if any of the pixelsin the set matches any of the pixels in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a faster way to make my loop run faster without NumPy and that is by using `sets`, which is way faster than using lists or NumPy. This is what the code looks like now:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("bg.jpg").convert("RGB")
pixels = img.load()

colors = set({})

for h in range(img.size[1]):
    for w in range(img.size[0]):
        if pixels[w,h] in colors:
            continue
        else:
            colors.add(pixels[w,h])
```

This solves my initial problem of the lists being too slow to loop through, and it goes around the second problem of NumPy unable to compare the tuples. Thanks for all the replies, have a good day.